# Expandir image, fuera de container con Bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero expandir mi imagen para que se desplace fuera del container, en este caso el container (color azul) la imagen expandirla al recuerdo color (rojo).
Como podria hacerlo con bootstrap?

```
  <div class="row mb-5">
     <div class="col-lg-6 pt-5">
     <h1 class="text-white">Integrate a esta plataforma medica para ginecología.</h1>
     <p class="lead">Una aplicación web que te ayudara a organizar tus expedientes médicos para tener acceso en cualquier parte del mundo.</p>
      <a style="float:none; display: inline-block" href="./" target="_blank" rel="noopener" class="button button--danger button--large">PROBAR GRATIS AHORA</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
  <img src="./walls_hero@2x.png" class="img-responsive">
  </div>
```

Comment: ¿Has probado dándole a la imagen un ancho arriba del 100%?

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias formas de hacerlo, una sería colocar 2 columnas como offset con esta linea:

```
<div class="col-lg-2"></div>
```

Quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
<div class="row mb-5">
    <div class="col-lg-6 pt-5">
        <h1 class="text-white">Integrate a esta plataforma medica para ginecología.</h1>
        <p class="lead">Una aplicación web que te ayudara a organizar tus expedientes médicos para tener acceso en cualquier parte del mundo.</p>
        <a style="float:none; display: inline-block" href="./" target="_blank" rel="noopener" class="button button--danger button--large">PROBAR GRATIS AHORA</a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-2"></div> <!-- Agregué esta linea -->

    <div class="col-lg-4"> <!-- Cambie a 4 columnas para la imagen debido al offset de 2 columnas -->
        <img src="./walls_hero@2x.png" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
</div>
```